# Making a drop-down menu keyboard and mouse browsable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

I am working on a project for a client that requires a custom drop-down menu, accessible by clicking to open it, or using the keyboard to tab across to it.

Currently, my solution works almost perfectly, but there is one problem: the first time you click the drop-down menu, it flashes open and then closes again. I'm sure there's a simple glitch with my JavaScript and jQuery here!

The required functionality is this:

1. The user must be able to click to open a drop-down menu. (DONE, but with problems)
2. The user must be able to click another menu, and have  the previous one close and the new one open. (DONE)
3. The user must be able to click anywhere else on the page and have the open menu close.  (DONE)
4. The user must be able to tab along the menu bar, highlighting each link, and opening the menu when it is tabbed to.  (DONE)
5. The tabbing must then tab down the entire menu, before leaving onto the next menu or link, closing the previous menu.  (DONE)

As I say here, I have it almost entirely working, but the keyboard focus recognition also detects mouse focusing, meaning that when I click, it triggers a keyboard focus instantly after the mouse one, closing it again.

Or so I think. Please help!

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function toggle(select) {
    closeAll(select);
    if(select.hasClass("expanded")) {
        select.removeClass("expanded");
    } else {
        select.addClass("expanded");
    }
}
function closeAll(select) {
    var close = $(document).find("#navigation li.select.expanded");
    if(select != null) {
        close = close.not(select);
    }
    close.removeClass("expanded")
}

$("#navigation > ul > li.select > a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggle($(this).parent());
});
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    var select = $("#navigation > ul > li.select.expanded");
    if(!select.is(event.target) && select.has(event.target).length === 0) {
        closeAll();
    }
});
$(document).on("focus", "#navigation > ul > li > a", function () {
    closeAll();
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("select")) {
        toggle($(this).parent());
    }
});
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
            <li class="select">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Find a Society</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Scotland</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">North West</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">North East</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Midlands</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Eastern Counties</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Central Counties</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">South West Counties</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Southern Counties</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">South East Counties</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Greater London</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**The current design**

[image: The current user-interface design]

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to create a similar dropdown with some complex features like typeahead list filtering and fixed this issue along the way.

The trick is to only have one entry point into your dropdown menu, every other method has to call this same event. In your case it's the tab focus, so you want to trigger this on click:

#### EDIT: Fix Open/Close as per OP comment

```
$("#navigation > ul > li.select > a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('expanded')){
        closeAll()
    }
    else {
        $(this).focus(); #Here the magic happens :)
    }
});
```

Now the click event triggers a tab focus event which then toggles the visibility of your dropdown.

Closing the dropdown when clicking outside can be simplified with event delegation and the css `:not()` selector. This should also be slightly faster than your current implementation, though the length of the css selector probably means not by much.

```
$(document).on('mouseup',':not(#navigation > ul > li.select.expanded)',(function(event) {
    closeAll();
});
```

By the way, your toggle function can be simplified using Jquery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
function toggle(select) {
    closeAll(select);
    select.toggleClass('expanded');
}
```

Comment: That seems promising! I'm just trying to finish getting it working, currently with that code the drop-downs don't close again on click.

Comment: @ProbabilityWolf, Good catch, I think my edit will fix this. In my version(working from memory now as I don't have it here), I use the `blur` event as the exit point, which focuses the next element and closes the next one. This could replace your `closeAll` function, but if it works for you, no need to fix it.

Comment: I must be making a serious mistake somewhere, it's still bouncing open and shut when I click it, despite the focus bit working.

Comment: If you could place your code in a JSFiddle I will try and find the problem

Comment: Good luck! I'm having some kind of a mental block about this problem. [http://jsfiddle.net/cfnhgyht/](http://jsfiddle.net/cfnhgyht/)

Comment: I'm not getting any bounce, it's working fine with no bounce in both Chrome and FF, but selecting an item  doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: to replicate the problem, try clicking on the blue bit on the right of the dropdown? Also, if you click the white of the dropdown it opens, but it doesn't close if clicked again.

Comment: @ProbabilityWolf, sorry. Only got your response now. Looks like my event delegation on mouseup isn't catching the event. I'm not able to wrap my head around the problem either, but it seems to stem from the fact that clicking on the icon triggers the focus immediately without the click.

Comment: @LcLx Hopefully I'll manage to find a solution then! It's a very weird problem.